# Receiving " Undefined variable: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\products\products.php on line 8 null"

Tags: php, android, null

I guess its a small problem but would love to be answered with explanation. The 8th line is producing undefined variable error (null).

```
<?PHP
include_once("connectionFile.php");
$query = "SELECT pid, name, qty, price, image_url FROM tbl_product ORDER BY pid DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: You fetched 0 rows, so you never created `$data`.

Comment: Check is there any resultset in `$result` or mysql execution error otherwise set `$data` to be empty string/object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the variable `$data` is not defined.

```
<?PHP
    include_once("connectionFile.php");
    $query = "SELECT pid, name, qty, price, image_url FROM tbl_product ORDER BY pid DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $data = array(); // add this or $data = [];
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
```

that's not a fatal error, just notice, you can set the error level via php.ini or error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE) function.

by the way, code like you write is so old, it's highly recommend to read `PHP The Right Way` http://www.phptherightway.com/

first answer and hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your $data outside of while loop. if you are declaring inside while loop scope of the $data is with in while loop, you cont use outside of while loop

```
<?PHP
include_once("connectionFile.php");
$query = "SELECT pid, name, qty, price, image_url FROM tbl_product ORDER BY pid DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$data=[];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Hope it will help